# I want my website to open in desktop view on mobile

Tags: php, html, css

**Hi, I'm developing a website, but I don't have time to deal with making it responsive, instead I want my website to open in a desktop view on mobile, what can I do for this?**

Comment: If you (developer) not provide responsive design(in css), your site open in desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

some time before i was wondering the same. then i found the button in devtools on chrome and in firefox. here are the images of where the buttons are:

In Chrome:
[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ3Qt.jpg)

[In Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIOb7.jpg)

Just click the buttons and you will see them!

Comment: Dude, you misunderstood me. I want the user visiting my site from a mobile device to always see the site in desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this from your html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Teşekkürler, artık ihtiyacım kalmadı. Ama deneyeceğim.